# How to implement signal slot in uwp

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, signals-slots

This is my project tree:

[image: project tree]

The project is a simple book manager. It interacts with a sqlite database.

YourBooks class looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class YourBooks : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Book> Books;

    public YourBooks()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DatabaseManager.InitializeDatabase();
        Books = DatabaseManager.GetBooks();
    }

    private async void Add_a_book_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This doesn't matter
    }
}
```

DatabaseManager class acts as a middle man between the application and the database. This is the code:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string CoverImage { get; set; }
}

class DatabaseManager
{
    public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("FileName= MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();

            string command = "create table if not exists MyBooks " +
                             "(title text primary key not null, author text not null, isbn text not null, quantity integer not null, " +
                             "CoverImage text not null)";

            SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(command, db);

            SqliteDataReader reader = createTable.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            { }
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("FileName=MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();

            string command = "select title, author, quantity, CoverImage from MyBooks";

            SqliteCommand getBooks = new SqliteCommand(command, db);

            SqliteDataReader dataReturned = getBooks.ExecuteReader();

            ObservableCollection<Book> books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
            while(dataReturned.Read())
            {
                books.Add(new Book
                {
                    Title = dataReturned.GetString(0),
                    Author = dataReturned.GetString(1),
                    Quantity = dataReturned.GetInt32(2),
                    CoverImage = dataReturned.GetString(3)
                });
            }

            return books;
        } 
    }

    public static void AddBook(string title, string author, string isbn, int quantity, string coverImageLocation)
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("FileName=MyBooks.db"))
        {
            db.Open();

            SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand
            {
                CommandText = "insert into MyBooks values (@title, @author, @isbn, @quantity, @coverImage)",
                Connection = db
            };

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", author);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", isbn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coverImage", coverImageLocation);

            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}
```

In my NewBooks class, I update the database like this:

```
DatabaseManager.AddBook(BookNameTextBox.Text, AuthorTextBox.Text, ISBNTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text), destinationFile.Path);
```

I want YourBooks class to be notified that the database has changed. Before UWP, I have little experience with Qt. And in Qt and it had signal and slot mechanism. So what you would do is you would define a signal that you could fire and the slot would be called.

How can I notify YourBooks from NewBook that the database has changed so that it can update itself.

Comment: Do you want to notify the GridView of your own changes or any changes that are being written to the database from some other location?

Comment: Yes @mm8. I want to notify the GridView

Comment: Of your own changes?

Comment: Like if I add a book to the database, I want to show using the grid view that the book has been added @mm8

Comment: You don't answer my question...how are you addding a book the the database?

Comment: I am adding it using DatabaseManager class (in file DataBaseModel.cs) which contains a static method to add a book. This whole thing happens in the NewBook.xaml.cs when the user clicks "add" on the NewBook page @mm8

Comment: And how are you poulating your GridView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178526/discussion-between-hemil-and-mm8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface in your `Book` class (or whatever your type is called) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever you set a property of it to a new value.

Then any UI element in the view that is bound to the corresponding property will be updated automatically.

If you add a new book to the database, you should also add a new `Book` object to the `ObservableCollection<T>` to which your `GridView` is bound.

In your case you could raise an event from the `DatabaseManager` class and handle the event in `YourBooks` class.

Comment: What I want is how can I update my Observable Collection as it is a totally different class. If I can get to do that, I can just re-assign my ObservableCollection to the database contents

Comment: So from where are you updating the database? You should do this from the view model where the ObservableCollection is defined, or at least initialize the operation from there.

Comment: I have a DatabaseManager class with static methods so that I can call them from anywhere in my project without objects. YourBooks class has an ObservableCollection which is initialized using DatabaseManager class. I make changes to the database in NewBook class. Now, I want the YourBooks class to be notified that the underlying database has changed so that it can upate itself.

Comment: Instead of trying to explain how your code looks like, please post it. I have already told you what to do.

Comment: *You* need to notify the view model. The database certainly won't do it for you in some magic way.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. I want to know how can I notify YourBooks from NewBook that the database has changed. I have updated the question. Hope I am more clear

Comment: Raise an event from the DatabaseManager class and handle the event in YourBooks.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. That's the answer. Not what you posted above

Comment: I edited the answer slightly based on your edit. Check again.